# MySQL Delete From Join Not Working

Tags: mysql

I've tried every which way that this site has to offer to get this query to work and each time with errors.

I have 2 tables:  lane and sale.

Here is just one of the syntax that I have tried:

```
delete lane from lane 
join sale on lane.id=sale.id
where sale.name='MySale' 
and lane.number=5
```

This particular query gives me the error:  Token lane was not valid.  Valid tokens: FROM

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: Odd as that is valid multi-table delete syntax. Can you talk more about how you are actually trying to query the database (i.e. what language, what DB connection library, etc.) as I am wondering if this error is being thrown by DB access layer.

Comment: Do you have a column named `lane` in table `lane`? Are you sure `lane.number` is a Number, not a String?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
delete from lane l
where l.salehid# in (select a.salehid# from sale a where a.name='MySale' )
and l.number=5
```